# Получить запрос в отношениях

Tags: laravel

помогите исправить запрос

```
$base = Base::where('group_id', 19)->load(['journal' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('year', 2020);
}]);
```

Ошибка  **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::load()**

Мне нужно выбрать group_id где = 19 и в отношения journal где year = 2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю что так должно быть запрос:

```
Base::with(['journal' => function($query) {
    $query->where('year', 2020);
    // Дополнительные запросы может быть здесь
    // Пример:
    // $query->where('foo', 'bar');
}])->where('group_id', 19)->get();
```

Comment: Супер! А подскажите если добавлять еще условия к $query->where('year', 2020), как это сделать ?

Comment: После с новой строки еще можете применить запрос типа так `$query->where('carModel', 'Lexus');` внутри анонимной функции